# Timelapse Google Earth Engine and QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, google-earth, google, google-earth-engine

**Any chance somebody is working on plugin for QGIS or know about any project trying to get Timelapse Google Earth Engine (imagery) into QGIS?**

There was a major update recently and it looks really useful for many implementations. If you don't know what I am talking about:

https://earthengine.google.com/timelapse/

"We sifted through about three quadrillion pixels—that’s 3 followed by 15 zeroes—from more than 5,000,000 satellite images … We took the best of all those pixels to create 33 images of the entire planet, one for each year. We then encoded these new 3.95 terapixel global images into just over 25,000,000 overlapping multi-resolution video tiles."

Comment: Are the images used in the timelapse (i.e. the "33 images of the entire planet, one for each year") available at https://code.earthengine.google.com/datasets?

Answer (score 1):

You can query the data yourself in Earth Engine and from there export it to QGIS if you must. The point is you won't be able to replicate the timelapses they have on your local machine because of the computing resources it requires to download, process and store all of the images. You can share and embed a timelapse and [create your own tour](http://timemachine.cmucreatelab.org/wiki/EarthEngineTourEditor).

Some info on the data sources:

> Using Earth Engine, we combined over 5 million satellite images acquired over the past three decades by 5 different satellites. The majority of the images come from Landsat, a joint USGS/NASA Earth observation program that has observed the Earth since the 1970s. For 2015 and 2016, we combined Landsat 8 imagery with imagery from Sentinel-2A, part of the European Commission and European Space Agency's Copernicus Earth observation program.

Here's the getting started page with some code to use Landsat data.
https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/getstarted